# SQL 'where' clause aggregation pulling multiple fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables relating to hospital activity; the first lists patient referrals with PATIENT_ID and REFERRAL_DATE, the second shows discharges with PATIENT_ID, DISCHARGE_DATE and DISCHARGE_LOCATION. Each patient can be referred and discharged many times

I’m trying to run a query that will give me each referral with the date of the subsequent discharge and the discharge location.

I’ve got this far (but can’t figure out how to work an aggregate function to pull in the DISCHARGE_LOCATION for the MIN(DISCHARGE_DATE)):

```
SELECT
Referral.PATIENT_ID,
Referral.REFERRAL_DATE,
MIN(Discharge.DISCHARGE_DATE) AS NEXT_DISCHARGE

FROM Referral
LEFT OUTER JOIN Discharge
ON Referral.PATIENT_ID = Discharge.PATIENT_ID
AND Discharge.DISCHARGE_DATE > Referral.REFERRAL_DATE

GROUP BY
Referral.PATIENT_ID,
Referral.REFERRAL_DATE
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Table examples:

```
Referral:
PATIENT_ID  REFERRAL_DATE
Patient1    10/08/2012
Patient1    05/09/2012
. . .

Discharge:
PATIENT_ID  DISCHARGE_DATE  DISCHARGE_LOCATION
Patient1    01/08/2012      Hospital
Patient1    25/08/2012      Home
Patient1    15/09/2012      Care Home
. . .
```

The outcome I’m looking for is:

```
PATIENT_ID  REFERRAL_DATE   NEXT_DISCHARGE  DISCHARGE_LOCATION
Patient1    10/08/2012      25/08/2012      Home
Patient1    05/09/2012      15/09/2012      Care Home
. . .
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join your results back to your discharge table to get the desired results.

```
select 
     results.*,
     discharge.DISCHARGE_LOCATION

from 
(
    SELECT
        Referral.PATIENT_ID,
        Referral.REFERRAL_DATE,
        MIN(Discharge.DISCHARGE_DATE) AS NEXT_DISCHARGE    
    FROM Referral
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Discharge
        ON Referral.PATIENT_ID = Discharge.PATIENT_ID
        AND Discharge.DISCHARGE_DATE > Referral.REFERRAL_DATE    
    GROUP BY
        Referral.PATIENT_ID,
        Referral.REFERRAL_DATE
) results
     left join discharge 
          on results.NEXT_DISCHARGE = discharge.discharge_date
          and results.patient_id = discharge.patient_id
```